# How do I apply multiple filters with angular2-datatable?

Tags: angular, filter, lodash

I'm currently using angular2-datatable in my project (found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable)

I've modified my filterQuery pipe so that I can choose the column that I want to filter on. Here's the code:

```js
export class DataMgmtFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {


  transform(array: any[], query: string, field: string, active: boolean, deleted: boolean): any {    

    if (query) {
      return _.filter(array, row => row[field].indexOf(query) > -1);
    }
    return array;
  }

}
```

My issue is that I also want to filter on active and deleted rows on top of the query string entered. I can't seem to figure out how to add those values to the search criteria.

I did put in some console.logs and see that the Active and Deleted booleans are being brought over, but my attempts at using lodash filtering are failing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you can add another pipe and chain it.

Comment: Lol well that makes sense. Worked out perfectly, not sure why I didn't think of that in the first place. Thanks @wannadream